# Javascript's document.write prevents following code execution

Tags: javascript

I understand `document.write` prevents the executing of following javascript.

For example the `document.write` will prevent the execution of the following javascript until the `document.write` block has completely executed.

```
<!doctype html>
<script>
document.write('<script>alert(1)<'+'/script>');
alert('2');  
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/alefob

You can take this even further and require for javascript to be loaded remotely before executing the following script.

```
<!doctype html>
<script>
document.write('<script src="remote_script.js"><'+'/script>');
alert(remote_script_variable);  
</script>
```

Obviously I could do a callback, but that's not what I'm looking for.

### Question

Basically do any other functions have this unique functionality of preventing scripts from loading until completion (others functions that I might want to avoid)?

Assuming that no other functions have this unique functionality.  Can `document.write` ever be used after page load without overwriting the pages content?

### Already Understood

I know you can do the following along with using `yennop.js`

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
var currentScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script,currentScript);
script.src = '//some url';
```

Comment: Generally `document.write()` should be avoided anyway.  No, you can't use it after the DOM is ready (that is, after the initial document is closed) without blowing away the page.

Comment: What about a `document.createFragment` or `iframe` trick?

Comment: A document fragment is like a "mini-DOM"; I know of no way to "open" it like a page document. Now, an iframe, yes, that would probably work. A big question would be, why would you want to do that, when there are so many better ways of creating new content?

Comment: Also, while it's true that "document.write" is synchronous, it doesn't take a significant amount of time to run.  It should be roughly the same as using ".innerHTML" to inject content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Synchronous XHR](http://blog.lexspoon.org/2009/01/just-how-evil-is-synchronous-xhr.html) stops the world in many browsers until the response is received or the request errors out.

And obviously, `document.writeln` stops the world in the same way as `document.write`.

Comment: Unfortunately `Synchronous XHR` isn't cross site compatible.

Comment: @Lime, you can address that by proxying content through a page on the same origin.

Comment: Interesting, because I though cross browser support for `Synchronous XHR` was poor.  That is why I thought jQuery has a callback function along with a handful of other libraries.

Comment: @Lime, Sorry.  I interpreted "cross-site" in your earlier post as a reference to the fact that XHR doesn't allow you to fetch content from a different origin than the page.  Did you mean to say that there are major browsers that do not support synchronous XHR?

Comment: Well I'm looking for a cross browser solution :D  as well as being Cross Origin compatible.  So well 2x, both